# SQL Server 2008 fulltext catalogs: more than one language?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have one table and I want to create two fulltext catalogues, one in German, and one in English.

My problem is:

I can only create one fulltext catalog per table, but I want to create a fulltext catalog for
English language and German language. I cannot use an indexed view.

Is there any way to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can create one fulltext index per table, that's true - but that index doesn't have to be for just a single language.

If you want, you can add some language hints to your CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX statement - if e.g. one column is the English text, while another one is the German description.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ProductDocs
(DocSummary, 
 DocContentEnglisch TYPE COLUMN FileExtension LANGUAGE 1033,
 DocContentGerman TYPE COLUMN FileExtension LANGUAGE 1031)
........
```

But you don't have to. SQL Server Fulltext indexing will work with multiple languages, no problem.

Check out [Understanding Fulltext Indexing in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) and [SQL Server Full Text Search Language Features](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features/) for more details.

Comment: Will the hint change which noise list is used?

Comment: I believe it does, yes - and also it'll influence which thesaurus to use when you search for stemmed words or synonyms